# Excel Copy Select and Paste into txt file on my desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot work out why when I run the script below it copies the selection correct, formats the `fName` correctly, then pastes to a new workbook successfully and then creates a txt file with nothing in it.

What I'm trying to do is take the selection I have copied and paste it into a new text file using the 'fName' as the filename of the file. thanks

```
 Sub SaveAsXML_txt()
'
' set the length of XML
Dim xmlLength As Integer
Dim fName As String
xmlLength = Range("I9")
fName = Range("I3") & " " & Range("I10") & " XML"
'
' set the filename of textfile
'
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
'
' References
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
'
' select the whole XML to copy
wsSource.Range("K2:K" & xmlLength).Copy
'
'Save in new workbook
wbDest.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks.Add.SaveAs fName, xlTextWindows

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs fName, xlTextWindows` statement is Adding a new workbook, and then immediately saving it.  Naturally enough, it will be empty.

You need to do a `wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlTextWindows` instead.

After saving it, you can do a `wbDest.Close False` to close it without saving.  (No point saving it a second time.)

Comment: thanks for your help here, I made the change and it created the file in my `Documents` folder. Mind you, it was open as a workbook on my desktop. Is there any way of getting to do it silently? I try to close the workbook it creates and I get the "Do you want to save?" question which I'm trying to avoid. I am creating this script so I can cycle through a load of text files that the script needs to create one after the next, thanks

Comment: @MattLightbourn - `wbDest.Close False`

Comment: @YouE3K awesome, thanks. I completely overlooked the last line :)

Comment: @MattLightbourn You didn't overlook the last line - I added it to the answer in response to your question.